# Pybaseball: Extract standings data and save to disk using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is take this output from pybaseball which is set in as a list.

> [ Tm W L W-L% GB 1 Boston Red Sox 94 44 .681 -- 2 New York Yankees 86 51 .628]

and put it into a csv file using pandas. So far these are the are the queries I have tried I have the information for this output set as data. Whenever I try to import it from `pd.DataFrame()` it tells me that:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'.

So I add a dataframe to that using `df = pd.Dataframe(data)` and that prints out just the headers

> 0 Teams     W     L  W-L%    GB
>   0    Tm    Tm
>   1     W     W
>   2     L     L
>   3  W-L%  W-L%
>   4    GB    GB

How would I get this to import all of the information in the list to csv?

```
from pybaseball import standings
import pandas as pd

data = standings()
data.to_csv('file.csv', header = True, sep = ',')
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Also, do not add information in the comments, but add them to the question.

Comment: What you need to do is two separate steps, which you can find with a quick Google search:  1) How to import a list into a pandas dataframe.  2) How to save a pandas dataframe in a csv file.
There is something else you should consider:  You don't need a pandas dataframe to save your list to csv.  You can also search how to save a 'list' or a 'list of lists' directly to a csv file, which is very efficient and easy, with no need for pandas.

Comment: thanks jberrio, ill do that and thanks for editing guys. will fix if i need to post again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `standings()` returns a `list` of `dataframes`:

```
from pybaseball import standings
import pandas as pd

data = standings()
print type(data)
print type(data[0])
```

Output:

```
<type 'list'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

To write it to file, you need to [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the list of dataframes into a single dataframe before writing:

```
all_data = pd.concat(data)
print all_data
all_data.to_csv("baseball_data.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

Output:

```
                      Tm   W   L  W-L%    GB
1         Boston Red Sox  95  44  .683    --
2       New York Yankees  86  52  .623   8.5
3         Tampa Bay Rays  74  63  .540  20.0
4      Toronto Blue Jays  62  75  .453  32.0
5      Baltimore Orioles  40  98  .290  54.5
1      Cleveland Indians  77  60  .562    --
2        Minnesota Twins  63  74  .460  14.0
3      Chicago White Sox  56  82  .406  21.5
4         Detroit Tigers  55  83  .399  22.5
5     Kansas City Royals  46  91  .336  31.0
1         Houston Astros  85  53  .616    --
2      Oakland Athletics  83  56  .597   2.5
3       Seattle Mariners  77  61  .558   8.0
4     Los Angeles Angels  67  71  .486  18.0
5          Texas Rangers  60  78  .435  25.0
1         Atlanta Braves  76  61  .555    --
2  Philadelphia Phillies  72  65  .526   4.0
3   Washington Nationals  69  69  .500   7.5
4          New York Mets  62  75  .453  14.0
5          Miami Marlins  55  83  .399  21.5
1           Chicago Cubs  81  56  .591    --
2      Milwaukee Brewers  78  61  .561   4.0
3    St. Louis Cardinals  76  62  .551   5.5
4     Pittsburgh Pirates  67  71  .486  14.5
5        Cincinnati Reds  59  79  .428  22.5
1       Colorado Rockies  75  62  .547    --
2    Los Angeles Dodgers  75  63  .543   0.5
3   Arizona Diamondbacks  74  64  .536   1.5
4   San Francisco Giants  68  71  .489   8.0
5       San Diego Padres  55  85  .393  21.5
```

And you'll have a file `baseball_data.csv` which is a comma-separated representation of the dataframe above.